# evaluate integral in spherical coordinates, answer keeps coming out wrong

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, euclidean-geometry

[image]

I replaced the inside of the integral with p^4 sin phi and evaluated this thing twice and get 2500pi every time, but the answer is 
312,500pi/7. I made sure not to pull out the negative before evaluating. i made sure the integral of sin is -cos. I checked the jacobian. i'm pretty sure i have the boundaries right. I need to figure out why I keep getting these types of problems wrong..

Comment: We can't help you find your mistake until you edit the question to post your work. Be sure to use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: When doing the integral, you'll get $\int_0^5 r^6\,dr$ times some stuff with angles in it.

Comment: oh i see, i plugged in p instead of p^2 for the part in parentheses.

Comment: In some cases, it can be helpful to include the source of the problems you are posting: Calculus: Early Transcendentals (8th Edition) page 1050.